# Website Header in HTML

Tags: html, layout

How do I create a webpage with a header, content, and a footer. I am using TextEdit on my Mac and saving the file with a .HTML extension.

Comment: Do you have access to a scripting language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go through the 3+3 tutorials for HTML and CSS on [HTML Dog](http://htmldog.com/).

Comment: @Sunny: The question was very basic and my answer did not have any RTFM tone in it :)

Comment: Undoing the downvote, as the OP accepts this, but still its better to provide a solution :)

Comment: @Sunny: Thanks. I still think that in this case the solution is to point the author to the tutorial itself instead of trying to guess what he means or copy pasting huge tutorial sections in here.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have some ability to run a scripting language on your host, so just write a header and footer file, and include those in your content page with your dynamic language of choice.

Answer (score 0):

create an html file paste this frames :

```
<html>

<frameset rows="25%,50%,25%">

  <frame src="header.htm">
  <frame src="content.htm">
  <frame src="footer.htm">

</frameset>

</html>
```

and then create your header, content and footer files in same directory.

Comment: Sweet god almighty, I thought we eradicated this like Polio!

Comment: Yes, frames suck but it's the only way to do modularization in a static html environment. So ++

Comment: No one is asking about file modularization. So this is heaping bad upon bad.

Comment: @Rex M: The question was very vague and it was not clear what the intention was.

Comment: @Rex M : strange people, he is not asking about file modularization, ok, but not asking for one and only one file.. it's an answer, and not wrong, like or dislike..

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head><title>my title</title></head>

<h1>My Header</h1>

<p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</p>

<h4>My footer</h4>
</html>
```

my title

## My Header

The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

My footer

---

Optionally, you can put each section in a separate file, or specifically the header and footer in separate files to be reused.

Answer (score 0):

If your web server is [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/) (I would guess on Mac), you can use [server-side includes](http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/creating/include.html):

```
<html>
.....
<body>
<!--#include virtual="myheader.html" --> 

YOUR CONTENT GOES HERE

<!--#include virtual="myfooter.html" --> 
</body>
```